Is it safe to use multithreading with DISM APIs to remove multiple items from an image simultaneously?
I didn't find anything on the documentation if its safe to perform multithreaded calls to DismRemovePackage, DismRemoveCapability, DismDisableFeature, i mean, attempt to remove multiple "things" from the image at once.
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dismapi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DismLogLevel dwLogLevel = DismLogLevel::DismLogErrors;
    HRESULT hr = DismInitialize(dwLogLevel, NULL, NULL);

    DismSession session = NULL;
    hr = DismOpenSession(L"V:\\", NULL, NULL, &session);

    hr = DismRemoveCapability(session, L"Print.Fax.Scan~~~~0.0.1.0", NULL, DismProgressCallback, NULL);
    // ...
    return 0;
}


For any function in Windows that is not explicitly specified that it is safe to call in a multithreaded situtation, assume it is not.
